# Dependency of non descendant in Bayesian Network

Tags: conditional-probability, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I am learning Probabilistic Graphical Models from a book by Daphne Koller and the basic definition of a Bayesian Network says this:

[image: Definition of Bayesian Network]

I tried to make a counter example to this and am confused if the definition takes into the consideration a following model.

[image]

Consider here the random variable **Grade G** . I would refer all variables with their first letter.

**P(G | D, I, R , P)   !=   P(G | D, I, R )**

(Independence of variable G from a non decescendant is violated)

Intuitively if we know that we got a very high recommendation(R) and did very poorly in the project(P) then this will definitely improve the probability that we got a good grade(G), given intelligence and difficulty , compared to no evidence given about the project(P). But according to the basic definition this should not be true as independence over non descendant is violated here.

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Your intuition is correct, that if R is observed then P and G are dependent. But that is not
what the definition says: it says "given the parents", that is if the parent values are observed.
As R is not observed , within this definition, then P and G remain (conditionally) independen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'non-descendant' in this case is the Project node.

What you're doing here is conditioning on R. This doesn't match with the statement
given in the text, since that statement is concerned with conditioning on
the parents of G.

It might interest you to know that this is an example of conditional
*dependence*.

Consider the following network:

$$ A \rightarrow C \leftarrow B $$

where $ A $ and $ B $ are the two parent nodes of $ C $.

It is true that

$$
P(A, B) = P(A)P(B)
$$

in that they are independent. Consequently, $ P(A \mid B) = P(A) $ and vice versa
for $ B $.

However, $ P(A, B \mid C) \neq P(A \mid C)P(B \mid C) $. Intuitively, if $ C$ happens then we get information
about the combined influence that both $ A $ and $ B $ had on $ C $;
as such, knowledge about $ A $ will influence our knowledge about $ B $.

To further specify this, let

$$
A \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.1)
$$
$$
B \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.1)
$$
$$
C \mid A, B \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.1 + (A \times B) 0.9)
$$

Now we'll show that $ P(A, B \mid C) \neq P(A \mid C)P(B \mid C) $
(which implies that $ A $ and $ B $ are not independent given $ C $).

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(A=1, B=1 \mid C=1)
& = \frac{P(C=1 \mid A=1, B=1)P(A=1, B=1)}{P(C=1)} \\
& = \frac{1 \cdot P(A=1)P(B=1)}{P(C=1)} \\
& = \frac{0.01}{P(C=1)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

whereas:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(A=1 \mid C=1)
& = \frac{P(C =1 \mid A = 1)P(A = 1)}{P(C=1)} \\
& = \frac{[P(C = 1 \mid A=1, B=1)P(B=1) + P(C = 1 \mid B = 0, A = 1)P(B = 0)]P(A = 1)}{P(C = 1)} \\
& = \frac{[P(B=1) + 0.1 \cdot P(B = 0)]P(A = 1)}{P(C = 1)} \\ 
& = \frac{[0.1 + 0.1 \cdot 0.9]P(A = 1)}{P(C = 1)} \\ 
& = \frac{0.019}{P(C = 1)} \\ 
& = P(B = 1 \mid C = 1) \text{ by symmetry} \\ 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now since $$ P(C = 1) = P(C = 1 \mid A = 1)P(A = 1) + P(C = 1 \mid A = 0) P(A = 0) = 0.029 $$ we have

$$
P(A =1, B = 1\mid C = 1) = \frac{0.01}{0.029} \approx 0.3448
$$

whereas

$$
P(A = 1 \mid C=1)P(B = 1 \mid C=1) = \frac{0.019^2}{0.029^2} \approx 0.4293
$$

Comment: Thanks @kevin. Yes I also figured out as I read further.